# is JavaFX Scene Builder available on linux support?

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I can't find JavaFX scene Builder Linux package on the Oracle official website 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/index.html
is there any Solution so that I can work on it on a Linux plateforme ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The MAC OS version also works on Linux, because SceneBuilder is 100% pure Java, mostly. Download the MacOS DMG file from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html

Then extract with 7-zip. It's a compressed HFS file system.

```
$ mkdir javafx_scenebuilder
$ 7z e -ojavafx_scenebuilder javafx_scenebuilder-1_0-macosx-universal.dmg
```

Now extract the HFS partition:

```
$ cd javafx_scenebuilder
$ 7z x 4.hfs
```

This will extract lots of files. You'll only need "JavaFX Scene Builder 1.0/JavaFX Scene Builder 1.0.app/Contents/Java". You can remove all other files. Start Scenebuilder:

```
$ cd "JavaFX Scene Builder 1.0/JavaFX Scene Builder 1.0.app/Contents/Java"
$ java -cp javafx-beans-dt.jar:javafx-designtime.jar:jfxrt.jar:SceneBuilder.jar com.oracle.javafx.authoring.Main
```

There'll be an exception upon start saying something about "ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.prism.es2.gl.x11.X11GLFactory", but it'll work anyway.

Note that you'll need JDK7u6 to run it.

Answer (score 10):

There is now an [official developer preview of SceneBuilder for Linux](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html).

[Release notes, installation instructions and known bugs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/release_notes_1-1/jsbpub-release_notes_1-1.htm).

This preview renders obsolete the clever workarounds posted in a previous questions to make use of Wine or the Mac OS X version of SceneBuilder on Linux.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Look at JavaFX Scene Builder.

[Developer Preview Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html)

Comment: Nice, there is really a preview version for download.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're right, there is no Linux version available yet, unfortunatly.

I asked on the JavaFX Forum earlier this year, you can find the answer from Jeff McDonald here:

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2369765&start=15&tstart=0

So I think you have 2 choices:

- Edit the FXML file manually
- Use a virtual machine where you install an OS supported by Scence Builder and you use it to edit the FXML files. (You could e.g. share a directory between the Linux host and the guest and keep the rest of the development on Linux.)

Comment: Thanks ,Util Oracle realize that the is plenty of Java Developer in linux , I think I'll go for the virtual machine thing

Answer (score 2):

i've got scene builder working on linux. 
1. got the MacOS edition (.dmg file) 
2. extracted .jar files 
3. created proper dir structure 
4. created a script that executes proper command
5. win

Answer (score 1):

One option, which I use until it is officially supported for Linux is to install the Windows version of Scene Builder through Wine.

Comment: there is an developer preview: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html